# How to loop and check in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, powershell-2.0

I'm have an csv file that look like this

```
Name          SMTPAddress    ExistHold 
John      jona@gmail.com      True
Hanah      Hannah@gmail.com      True
David     david@gmail.com     False
```

and I'm just wondering how can I loop thru the list to see which users have ExistHold = True and get all those user SMTP address so that I can do the next process with only those users.

```
$Global:downloadFile = "C:\AuditLogSearch\Downloaded-Audit-Log-Records.csv"

function FunctionName {
    $importDownload = Import-Csv -Path $Global:downloadFile

    $importDownload | ForEach-Object{
      
    }
}
```

I'm kinda stuck with how to loop so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

Comment: You're looping already! Just add some code to the empty scriptblock after `ForEach-Object` and it'll execute once for each row/object in `$importDownload`.

Comment: First of all, your CSV seems to be actually a TSV (use ``-Delimiter "`t"`` )

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's where I'm not sure what to do in empty scriptblock after ForEach-Object. I just google but I can't find the one I wanted to do.

Comment: @ziico `$_` has the current object assigned on each iteration, so to get the value of the `ExistHold` property, you'd do `$_.ExistHold`. The documentation for the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) also has some good examples

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a Where-Object clause to get these users and don't need a loop:

```
# use a Where-Object clause to filter only items where field 'ExistHold' is set to 'True'
$importDownload = Import-Csv -Path $Global:downloadFile | Where-Object { $_.ExistHold -eq 'True' }

# you now have an array of objects and to get just the SMTPAddress simply do
$importDownload.SMTPAddress
```

<sup>`Import-Csv` by default expects a *comma* as delimiter character. If your file uses something else to separate the fields, like a TAB, you need to specify that with parameter `` -Delimiter "`t" ``</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the ForEach instead of ForEach object, sometimes it can be easier to work with.
If you import the CSV with the correct delimiter, you should be able to filter on it like this

```
$Global:downloadFile = "C:\AuditLogSearch\Downloaded-Audit-Log-Records.csv"

function FunctionName {
    $importDownload = Import-Csv -Path $Global:downloadFile

    ForEach ($import in $importDownload) {
       If ($import.ExistHold) {
           Write-Output "Its true :)"
       }
    }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's file is a TSV not a CSV on the other hand, the values of `ExistHold` are `strings`, your condition will always evaluate to `$true`.